# PHP filter_input REQUEST_TIME

Tags: php, filter-input

`filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_TIME')` returns nothing.

as opposed to directly accessing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']`, which returns proper number.

Am I doing something wrong? *HTTP_USER_AGENT* for example is returned ok.

I searched for it and didn't find any, seems like *REQUEST_TIME* is not accessible through `filter_input` for some reason.

Tested on PHP 5.6 and 7.0.

Comment: [It seems to be a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61497)(from 2012!) Quick check of what *is* available to you from `_SERVER`: `var_dump(filter_input_array(INPUT_SERVER));`

Comment: @burian.vlastimil I think I have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't quote me, but something like this is your problem.
REQUEST_TIME is added to $_SERVER after the HTTP REQUEST is processed by your web server (or, more accurately, by the PHP module). It does not appear in the HTTP headers/query string, blah, blah, blah, so you cannot filter REQUEST_TIME like you can HTTP_HOST, HTTP_USER_AGENT, REQUEST_URI, or USER_IP. I use the PHP filter functions, too. To verify my pseudo-answer, use ...

```
if(filter_has_var(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_TIME'))
{
     echo 'REQUEST_TIME is filterable with filter_input()';
}
else
{ 
     echo 'TOUGH LUCK';  //Kidding.
}
```

I just tested this on PHP 5.6.11. I feel that I am correct. The code responded 'TOUGH LUCK'. So, similar to SERVER_NAME, REQUEST_TIME is an internal value. The difference being that SERVER_NAME is present during the "magic time." REQUEST_TIME is added afterward. Go figure.